# Is it 'a' L-formula or 'an' L-formula?

Tags: word-usage, pronunciation, articles, hyphenation, appropriate

In Logic & Mathematics textbooks, the terms 'L-formula', or 'L-term', or 'L-theory' are used. (Though for math, it is reserved to mathematical logic.)

I've witnessed it first-hand, and I'm sure many did also, where authors will alternate between using the articles 'a' & 'an' quite a lot. I assume it's due to the pronunciation: it's odd to say 'a Ell formula' ('an' would be more appropriate in that case) versus 'a L-formula' (do not say 'L'); it raises the question, which is more appropriate?

##### Examples

> Let L be a signature (language), and let the formula X, be an L-formula.

> It is the case that a L-theory Y is incomplete if one of its formulae cannot be proven true or false.

> All the terms v, w, y belong to the universe of L, and thus an L-term is born.

---

**Note that**... The context may be a factor at play, the author may want to remind us that the formula is still *an* L-formula, but wanting to focus more on proving a point (say, the requirements for something to be a formula), then they might say *a* L-formula.

Comment: No. They cannot ever say "eh ell". It is not grammatical.

Comment: @tchrist, do you care to clarify?

Answer (score 2):

Whether to use "a" or "an" is determined by the pronunciation.  Since I pronounce "L" as *ell*, I would say "an L-formula".  Perhaps others pronounce "L" in other ways; their pronunciation will determine whether they write "a" or "an".

---

For example, "L" may sometimes be pronounced *fifty*, but not in this context.

Comment: Yes.  Oddly enough, "L-formula" begins with a vowel sound (the "e" in "ell"), and so the term should be preceded by "an", not "a".

Comment: @tchrist, no. His answer was beneficial too.